# Do I need a Thailand visa if departing from Malaysia

Tags: visas, thailand

According to The Bangkok US Embassy [web site](http://bangkok.usembassy.gov/service/thai-visas-for-americans.html) it says this:

> U.S. citizens carrying a tourist passport and in possession of an
>   onward or return airline ticket do not require a visa to enter
>   Thailand.

Now, what if the return ticket is from another country (like Malaysia)?

So, if I were to take a train to Kuala Lumpur, would I need to obtain a visa? Or, will they not care because I'm leaving the country and I at least have a return ticket.

The total trip will only be 7 days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter where your ticket will take you, as long as it will take you out of Thailand.  That's why it says "onward or return" ticket.

Comment: Figured as much, but didn't know if there were any special rules to consider. Thanks.

Comment: While it can be inferred that a flight out Malaysia means the OP will leave Thailand accordingly, it does not satisfy the Thai requirement of showing onward travel out of Thailand, itself. Fortunately Immigration rarely asks for proof (unless you look slovenly or broke), but the airline flying the OP to Thailand will check.

Comment: @Tom I'm confused. How does a round trip ticket Malaysia-Thailand-Malaysia fail to satisfy the requirement to show onward travel out of Thailand?

Comment: @phoog My interpretation of the question was that the OP booked Other country-Thailand//Malaysia-Other country, not Malaysia-Thailand-Malaysia.

Comment: @phoog - The OP specified his return ticket was not from Thailand, but from 'another country like Malaysia'.  In addition it is mentioned a possible return to Malaysia by train, so apparently no round trip air ticket between Malaysia and Thailand either.  Train and bus tickets don't qualify as exit proof since they often require switching conveyances at the border.

Comment: @Tom -- _some_ airlines will check.  Japanese and, for some reason, New Zealand airlines are known for being zealous.

Answer (score 1):

They don't know or care where you're coming from.  They don't know or care where you're going.

Supposedly, they care that you do leave, but the truth is, if you are white or have a passport from a white-people country, they don't even care about that.

Once I entered Thailand *by mistake*.  My ticket was (IIRC) to Saigon, but I thought it was two tickets, not a layover.  Nobody mentioned anything, until I tried to get my boarding pass to leave, and they definitely wanted their 500-baht airport fee, in cash.

If you are from India or China or, Buddha forbid, Cambodia, then yeah, they might want to see your return ticket.